# how to calculate the speed of memory

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware

I checked my Mac, it shows the memory is 16 GB 2400 Mhz, does it mean that the bandwidth is $ \dfrac{16\times1024}{8} \times 2400$, is there any thing wrong with that calculation, because the value seems a little incredible, I am new to this kind of computer science, hope someone can help me.
Thank You

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show your reasoning for multiple and dividing numbers in that way?  That might help us give you a more useful answer.  It might also help if you told us in a little more detail what you mean by "speed of memory", i.e., what you want to measure.

Comment: Are my socks any faster when I put them into a bigger drawer?